# fetching ordered pair of values

Tags: java, collections

I am looking to implement a data structure that would add / render an ordered pair of values. eg.

```
orderedPair.add(value1, text1)  
orderedPair.add(value1, text2)  
orderedPair.add(value2, text3, data1)  
orderedPair.add(value2, data2)  
orderedPair.add(value1, text5)
```

When I get, I want it to return iteratively as

```
value1, text1  
value1, text2  
value2, text3, data1 and so on.
```

LinkedHashMaps or any variants of HashMaps do not work since they return only the value based on key and what I am trying to get is value, value pairs. Note that neither value / text or data are unique and I may not be able to fetch it based on any keys. Also, i do NOT want a sorted list, I do need an ORDERED list only.

Question is: Is there any data structure in Java that can be used to accomplish this?

I did not come across any that serves this purpose. In which case I am pondering about writing a custom collection that would accomplish this. Any suggestions / help is welcome.

Comment: Also, I am trying to avoid using a 2d array

Comment: I might be misunderstanding the issue: why doesn't just `List<Tuple>` fits? where `Tuple` is a class defined by you that hold the relevant element types?

Comment: Thanks amit for responding.. is it something like a class with 2 or 3 values you mean? eg. OrderedPair{ String s1; String s2; int i1;}  but then would I not have to implement/Override all the methods of List anyway?

Comment: It is something that you will create - If you need 2-3 values: do it, it can also be implemented as a container for another list.

Comment: ok, thanks.. let me give it a try..

Comment: where did text5 go in the output?

Comment: @conphident4: You are welcome. I wrapped this litle discussion as an answer as well.

Answer (score 2):

Wrapping the discussion in the comments into an answer, since it seems to be useful to the OP:

Create a `class Tuple`, which will be your pairs/triples.

Note that this class can be implemented with a fixed number of parameters or as a container that holds a list of objects.

Hold these `Tuple` objects in a `List<Tuple>`, and you are done.

You can also implement `hashCode()`, `equals()` and make it implement `Comparable` to this class - and you will be able to use it with other collections such as `TreeSet` and `HashSet`.

Comment: btw this is my favourite [Tuple implementation](https://github.com/ripper234/Basic/tree/master/java/src/main/java/org/basic/datastructures/tuple) ... with [tests](https://github.com/ripper234/Basic/blob/master/java/src/test/java/org/basic/datastructures/tuple/TupleTester.java)

Answer (score 0):

Just use a Map of Lists, like Treemap

```
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> content = new Treemap<Integer, List<Integer>>();

if (not content.containsKey(value1)) {
   content.put(value1, new LinkedList<Integer>());
}
content.get(value1).add(text1)
```

This would be the function orderedPair.add

Then for output, traverse the Map and for each entry, write out each item of the corresponding List

Since you want to have it ordered, pass a Comparator to the Treemap constructor.

Comment: Note that it is `Map<T,V>` and not `Map<T>` [same goes for `TreeMap`]. Are you looking for a `Set<T>`?